# Unit tests with IEnumerable<Guid> in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a unit test for one of the stored procedures. In the model I'm passing it as a list of guid later on to the stored procedure I'm serializing it because SQL doesn't accept a list of GUID.

I'm kind of confused about how I should initialize it for the unit test, data on stored procedure

```
IEnumerable<Guid> aOfferId
```

This is the stored procedure class:

```
{
    [Schema(SqlSchema.Offer)]
    public class testO : StoredProcedure<int>
    {
        public testO(Guid tId,IEnumerable<Guid>OfferId, Guid userId)
        {
             TID = tId;
             AdvertOfferId =JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertOfferId);
           PUserId = userId;
        }

        public override Task<int> RunAsync() => ExecuteAsync();

    }
}
```

AdvertOfferId = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertOfferId);

```
{
    using System;
    s;
    using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    [TestClass]
    public class testOTests
    {

        [TestMethod]
        public void NonNullTests()
        {
           // var advertOfferSerialize= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertOfferId);
            var sproc = new testO(tId, aId, userId);
            Assert.AreEqual(aId, sproc.AId);
        }
    }
}
```

My test fails if I initialize data like the above.

Comment: Can you also share the code which you are trying to unit test?

Comment: In `NonNullTests`, you should do `advertOfferId = new List<Guid>();` and add values to it by doing `advertOfferId.Add(Guid.NewGuid());`. And then pass `advertOfferId` to the constructor of `ArchiveCpgOffer`.

Comment: it's failing where where a passing list of Ienumerable<GUID> I had to serialize advert offer cause SQL doesn't accept a list of GUID.

Comment: @Chetan still failing. I'm not sure if I  got  it correct.

Comment: can you explain `still failing.`? you should do `var advertOfferSerialize= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertOfferId);` after adding all the Guids to `advertOfferId` and us it in Assert. `Assert.AreEqual(advertOfferSerialize, sproc.AdvertOfferId);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask me, this is how it should work:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using CCE.Core.Models.SQL.Schemas.Offer.StoredProcedures;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace CCE.Offers.UnitTests.SQL.StoredProcedure
{ 
    [TestClass]
    public class ArchiveCpgOfferTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void NonNullTests()
        {
            //arrange
            var tenantId = Guid.Empty;
            var portalUserId = Guid.Empty;
            var advertOfferId = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid() };

            var advertOfferSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(advertOfferId);

            //act
            var sproc = new ArchiveCpgOffer(tenantId, advertOfferId, portalUserId);

            //assert
            Assert.AreEqual(advertOfferSerialized, sproc.AdvertOfferId);

            //this assertion does not make sense, it's always true:
            //Assert.IsNotNull(sproc);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how useful your scenario is, but this way it should compile and run.

Comment: thank you its clear to me now

Comment: you're welcome. if this is the answer you were looking for, please vote it up and accept the answer